# New Java programmer, basic java composition

Tags: java, composition

I am a new computer programming student. I watched a video about Java, basic composition, and the guy in the video made an example about this topic like this:

```
public class PaperTray
{
  int pages = 0;
  ....
  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return pages > 0;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Printer extends Machine
{
  private PaperTray paperTray = new PaperTray();
  ....
  public void print(int copies)
  {
  ....
  while(copies > 0 && !paperTray.isEmpty() )
  {
    System.out.println("some text to print");
    copies--;
  }
  if(paperTray.isEmpty())
  {
    System.out.println("load paper");
  }
}
```

My question is if the paper tray is empty, then in class PaperTray the method isEmpty() will return false. Therefore, the if statement in the class Printer will not be executed. And if the paper tray is not empty, the method isEmpty() in class PaperTray will return true, so the while statement in the class Printer will not be executed.
Am I wrong, or the instructor in the video clip made some mistakes?

Thank you

Comment: you have named the method in PaperTray as isEmpty() ,so logically it should return true when the tray is empty.

Comment: This code is written by the instructor named John Sonmez on PluralSight page

Answer (score 5):

The logic of the `isEmpty` does not make sense: I wold expect either

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return pages == 0;
}
```

or

```
public boolean isNotEmpty() {
    return pages > 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to return pages == 0; and twisted a little bit in the while loop, it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> if the paper tray is empty, then in class `PaperTray` the method `isEmpty()` will return `false`

It should return `true` (for any sensible implementation, that is :-). For a method called `isEmpty()`, common sense dictates that it returns `true` when the enclosing object / collection *is empty*, and `false` when it is *not* empty.

In other words, the implementation you show above has a bug.

Comment: so the initial value of pages is 0, so if the paper tray is empty which means the pages is 0, 0 cannot be greater than 0, so the method isEmpty() should return false??

Comment: @JackyNguyen, indeed it does - *now*. That's why I wrote that the current implementation of `isEmpty()` is incorrect: it should return `true` when - and only when - `pages == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I am the instructor from the video.
Thanks for catching this mistake.  You are correct.  At some point in recording the video I must have had the > 0 in there instead of <= 0.

Good catch.  It should be

```
public class PaperTray
{
  int pages = 0;
  ....
  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return pages <= 0;
  }
}
```

I checked the sample code for the course that is downloadable and it is correct there and everywhere else that class appears in the course, so it must have been just that one spot.

Thanks again for catching that error and my apologies for the mistake and the confusion it cost you.  Hopefully you were still able to benefit from the course.

Comment: Hi John, I really like your course, it is really helpful especially the collection, and generic module. I hope you will post more advance Java course such as programming in java with database,... Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you say is correct. `isEmpty()` should return true when it is empty. Probably an error on the instructors part.

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in the code: when copies are being made then only `copies` is decremented. But the code should also decrement the value of `pages` in `PaperTray`, otherwise there is no paper being used to make the copies.

When that happens, the code is fine:

```
while(copies > 0 && !paperTray.isEmpty() )
{
System.out.println("some text to print");
copies--;
}
if(paperTray.isEmpty())
{
System.out.println("load paper");
}
```

It will keep making the desired number of copies as long as there is paper in the tray. When there is no paper anymore, the while loop will exit. Either way, a check is performed at the end to tell the user the refill the paper tray when it is empty.

Comment: Yeah, there is a method to decrement the value of pages in PaperTray too, but my point here is if the instructor in the video made a mistake with the method isEmpty(), and whether the method isEmpty() return true if the paper tray is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a couple of issues with this code:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    //return pages > 0; this doesnt make sense
    return pages==0; 
}

public void print(int copies){
    while(copies > 0 && !paperTray.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("some text to print");
        pages--;//this is not enough. You need to decrement copies as well
    }

    if(paperTray.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("load paper");
}
```